# Null exception while working with joining tables in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have `product`, `Productsize` and `Size` entities.

`Productsize` entity contains `ProductID` and `SizeID` which are foreign key of `Product` and `Size` entity. I am adding size filter in shop page. List of size ids are coming from view .I am checking if the size ids are there in `Productsize` entity and displaying that product only.
In if condition it is showing null exception

```
List<int> sizeIDs = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(SizeIds) ? SizeIds.Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToList() : new List<int>();

var products = db.Products.ToList();

if (sizeIDs.Any())
{
    products = products.Where(x=>sizeIDs.Contains(x.ProductSizes.FirstOrDefault()
                                          .SizeID)).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
List<int> sizeIDs = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(SizeIds) ? SizeIds.Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToList() : new List<int>();

var products = db.Products.ToList();

if (sizeIDs.Any())
{
    products = products.Where(x=>sizeIDs.Contains(x.ProductSizes.FirstOrDefault()?
                                          .SizeID)).ToList();
}
```

.FirstOrDefault()**?**.SizeID

or :

```
List<int> sizeIDs = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(SizeIds) ? SizeIds.Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToList() : new List<int>();

var products = db.Products.ToList();

if (sizeIDs.Any())
{
    products = products.Where(x=>x.ProductSizes.Any() && sizeIDs.Contains(x.ProductSizes.First().SizeID)).ToList();
}
```

**Update:**
lets try this query:

```
List<int> sizeIDs = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(SizeIds) ? SizeIds.Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToList() : new List<int>();

            var products = db.Products.ToList();

            if (sizeIDs.Any())
            {
                products = products.Where(x => x.ProductSizes.Any(s=> sizeIDs.Contains(s.SizeID)) ).ToList();
            }
```

Comment: First solution not working. For second one `products = products.Where(x=>x.ProductSizes.Any() && sizeIDs.Contains(x.ProductSizes.First().SizeID)).ToList();` it showing result in case u are choosing the first size id i.e, first value available in Productsizes entity. for other sizes it is showing 0 products

Comment: @Anonymous please try update

Comment: Great . Update one worked. Thanks was trying this from 1 day